# The linearization of a gradient vector field along a heteroclinic connection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A gradient vector field $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has two equilibria  $x_1, x_2$. The vector field   defines a cooperative dynamical system. The linearization about $x_1$ has one positive eigenvalues and n-1 negative, while  about $x_2$, n negative eigenvalues.  Let $x(t)$ be the heteroclinic connection of the two equilibria (the mountain pass).

My question is: is it  true that the matrix $D_{x(t)}X$ of the linearization of the gradient system along $x(t)$, $\dot{\xi}=D_{x(t)}X\: \xi$, has a decreasing trace  with respect to t?

Thank you.